# Como ver el template para MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

He trabajado con mvc 4 mucho tiempo en mi ordenador . Sucede que ahora debo hacer un proyecto en mvc 5 por asuntos de estudios pero no veo el template para hacerlo. Estoy usando Visual Studio 2017 y .net 4.8 .[image: Esta es la ventana para crear el proyecto , como ven solo puedo seleccionar mvc4]

Answer (score 0):

Ese mismo de mvc que aparece es de MVC5,  también puedes seleccionar empty y marcar el check de MVC para crear uno en blanco sin las librerías que incluye el template básico.

Si deseas crear uno en mvc 4, en el menú anterior cuando seleccionas ASP. NET, si lo expande dice versiones anteriores y podrás realizarlo en mvc4 con su versión de Net correspondiente.